# How to write a nested multi dimensional json object

Tags: jquery, json

I am studying json and i was wondering if this is the right way to write a multi dimensional json object that is nested.I wrote:

```
var foo = {
    "logged_in":true,
    "town":"Dublin",
    "state":"Ohio",
    "country":"USA",
    "products":2,
    "0":{
        "pic_id":"1500",
        "description":"Picture of a computer",
        "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
        "type":"jpg",
        "childrenimages":2

        "0":{
        "pic_id":"15011",
        "description":"Picture of a cpu",
        "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/mycpu.png",
        "type":"png"
          }
        "1":{
        "pic_id":"15012",
        "description":"Picture of a cpu two",
        "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/thiscpu.png",
        "type":"png"
          }
    },
    "1":{
        "pic_id":"1501",
        "description":"Picture of a cpu",
        "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/cpu.png",
        "type":"png"
    }
};
```

Is this right or is there a convention i should follow if my object becomes too deeply nested.

Comment: You're assigning an Object value to a variable whose name implies that it holds a String value...

Comment: If you meant "0" and "1" to represent objects in an array you would us array notation `[]` and don't specify "0" or "1".   Something like https://gist.github.com/2875889  Note, there are lots of little problems with what you have written, which underlines the point made below....don't write JSON.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Consider using arrays instead of numerated object.

Arrays in json are defined using []
http://www.json.org/

Here is an example:

```
var foo = {
    "logged_in":true,
    "town":"Dublin",
    "state":"Ohio",
    "country":"USA",
    "products":
    [
        {
            "pic_id":"1500",
            "description":"Picture of a computer",
            "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
            "type":"jpg",
            "childrenimages":
            [
                {
                    "pic_id":"15011",
                    "description":"Picture of a cpu",
                    "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/mycpu.png",
                    "type":"png"
                },
                {
                    "pic_id":"15012",
                    "description":"Picture of a cpu two",
                    "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/thiscpu.png",
                    "type":"png"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "pic_id":"1501",
            "description":"Picture of a cpu",
            "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/cpu.png",
            "type":"png"
        }
    ],
};
```

(Forgive me if I forgot either closing { or [ or , its pretty hard to type code in SO :p )

This way you dont even need to have counts like

```
"products":2,
```

or

```
"childrenimages":2
```

You simply do

```
foo.products.length
```

or

```
foo.products[0].childrenimages.length
```

Good luck :)

Comment: This is actually a sane suggestion, using numeric indexes as object property names makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

That's not actually an array that you have there, that's just an object containing properties that are also objects.  You're also missing a few commas so this won't even compile.

What might be more convenient for you in this case is to use both arrays and objects to form your JSON.  For Example:

```
 var this_json_string = {
    "state":"Ohio",
    "country":"USA",
    "products":[
        {
          "pic_id":"1500",
          "description":"Picture of a computer",
        },

        {
          "pic_id":"15011",
          "description":"Picture of a cpu"
        },
        {
          "pic_id":"15012",
          "description":"Picture of a cpu two"
        },
        {
          "pic_id":"1501",
          "description":"Picture of a cpu"
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper format for your data (note i changed some data itself)

```
{
    "logged_in":true,
    "town":"Dublin",
    "state":"Ohio",
    "country":"USA",
    "products":2,
    "productinfo":[
        {
            "0":{
                "pic_id":"1500",
                "description":"Picture of a computer",
                "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
                "type":"jpg",
                "childrenimages":2
            },
            "1":{
                "pic_id":"15011",
                "description":"Picture of a cpu",
                "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/mycpu.png",
                "type":"png"
            },
            "2":{
                "pic_id":"15012",
                "description":"Picture of a cpu two",
                "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/thiscpu.png",
                "type":"png"
            },
            "3":{
                "pic_id":"1501",
                "description":"Picture of a cpu",
                "localion":"img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/cpu.png",
                "type":"png"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Don't write JSON. Seriously, except for simple configuration files, don't write JSON.

You have utilities to convert objects to a JSON string in most languages (if not any).

PHP: `json_encode($array);`

Javascript: `JSON.stringify( obj );`

Etc.

Writing JSON manually often leads to syntax errors. The kind that gives you headaches until you see that missing comma or w/e. You have good tools to do this, use them. You could compare to XML, but JSON has no tool (IDEs, text editor) saying "This syntax is wrong" while you're typing it. For example, no editor will tell you that you used a single quote instead of a double.

Just don't write JSON.

Comment: What are your statements against writing JSON? I see no point in your answer.

Comment: Because writing JSON manually often leads to errors that wouldn't happen if you use the methods provided by most languages. Why risking this kind of error when you can avoid them?

Comment: @skwee you sure ? he is suggesting you to create a native object in the langauge and then stringify json out of it :P so what you are doing is actually writing JSON the WAY WHICH IT DOES NOT FAILS AND ERROS

Comment: It's the same argument that XML was never meant to be written by hand.  If you knew the proper languages you could write a database by hand, but that would be absurd.  The same with JSON.

Comment: @JamesP.Wright except JSON doesn't have the same tools to write without syntax error (IDEs, whatever). For example, using single quote instead of double won't tell you "it's wrong" anywhere.

Comment: The question was how to write multi dimensional JSON object. @Florian Margaine answer neither answers the original question, nor brings any arguments against writing JSON (which might be useful in certain situations). As for "Writing JSON manually often leads to syntax errors." I can say the same about any dynamic programming language. JSON is a tool and like very tool it have its uses and needs to be "mastered" to be used correctly.

Comment: @skwee Let me add the "no tool shows syntax error like for XML" argument to the answer then :)

Comment: I think the source of confusion here is that the OP's code is not JSON. It's a JavaScript object literal, so in this case the interpreter will catch any syntax errors and usually show the line on which they occur. So, while this answer makes a good point, it might not be relevant in this particular context.

Comment: @Florian Margaine PHPStorm (or its little brother WebStorm) by JetBrains marks single quotes as invalid syntax as well as missing comma or unclosed array/object.
If you dont know the tools it dosent mean they dont exist ;)

Comment: @skwee sorry, I guess I misphrased. When I say "no tool", I know there are, but I mostly meant "not the most used IDEs/text editors" (eclipse, netbeans, emacs, vim, aptana...).

Comment: @Florian Margaine JetBrains tools are very popular and very professional