# reformat json from database query

Tags: java, mysql, json, multidimensional-array

This is my current

```
[{
    "year": "2015",
    "org_name": "MOOE",
    "suborg_name": "Forms Expenses",
    "amt": "2",
    "org_id": "4",
    "suborg_id": "24"
}, {
    "year": "2016",
    "org_name": "MOOE",
    "suborg_name": "Forms Expenses",
    "amt": "1",
    "org_id": "4",
    "suborg_id": "24"
}]
```

I want to get this format

```
[{
    "org_name": "MOOE",
    "suborg_name": "Forms Expenses",
    "suborg_id": "24",
    "org_id": "4",
    "Year": [{
        "year": "2015",
        "amt": "2"
    }, {
        "year": "2016",
        "amt": "1"
    }]
}]
```

Below is how I get my current values:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs2.next()) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    if (!rs2.getString("suborg_id").isEmpty()) {
        json.put("org_name", org_name);
        json.put("year", year);
        json.put("suborg_name", suborg_name);
        json.put("amt", amt);
        json.put("org_id", org_id);
        json.put("suborg_id", suborg_id);
    }

    finaljson2.put(counter2, json.toString());
    counter2++;
    list.add("" + json + "");
}

//out.println("[" + finaljson2.toString() + "]");
out.println(list);
```

I put in the if statement hoping it will group same `suborg_id`

`UPDATE`

Tried adding the year and amount to new array before pushing to json like

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs2.next()) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();

    if (!rs2.getString("suborg_id").isEmpty()) {

        json.put("year", year);
        json.put("amt", amt);


        json.put("org_name", org_name);
        json.put("suborg_name", suborg_name);
        json.put("org_id", org_id);
        json.put("suborg_id", suborg_id);
        json.put("year", json1);
    }

    finaljson2.put(counter2, json.toString());
    counter2++;
    list.add("" + json + "");
}

//out.println("[" + finaljson2.toString() + "]");
out.println(list);
```

My ouput looks like:

```
[{
    "org_name": "MOOE",
    "suborg_name": "Forms Expenses",
    "org_id": "4",
    "suborg_id": "24",
    "year": {
        "year": "2015",
        "amt": "2"
    }
}, {
    "org_name": "MOOE",
    "suborg_name": "Forms Expenses",
    "org_id": "4",
    "suborg_id": "24",
    "year": {
        "year": "20165",
        "amt": "1"
    }
}]
```

***My aim is to get the format***

```
[{
    "org_name": "MOOE",
    "suborg_name": "Forms Expenses",
    "suborg_id": "24",
    "org_id": "4",
    "Year": [{
        "year": "2015",
        "amt": "2"
    }, {
        "year": "2016",
        "amt": "1"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: And what might be the problem?

Comment: i need to create a multi dimensional array from the result of query. the problem is ii am not able to create it as multi dimensional it always ends up sa just single @Burkhard

Comment: @Burkhard i have update kindly check

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (rs2.next()) {
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 if (!rs2.getString("suborg_id").isEmpty()) {
 json.put("org_name", org_name);
 json.put("suborg_name", suborg_name);
 json.put("org_id", org_id);
 json.put("suborg_id", suborg_id);
 json.put("year");  

 [{
   json.put("year", year);  
   json.put("amt", amt);
  },{
   json.put("year", year);  
  json.put("amt", amt);
  }]

 }
finaljson2.put(counter2, json.toString());
counter2++;
list.add("" + json + "");
}
```

Comment: getting error here `json.put("year");` says `no suitable method for put(String)`

Comment: check this thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900235/how-to-write-a-nested-multi-dimensional-json-object may b you get idea from this

Comment: it is php i think in java its different